# Writing the byte array to sub folder in java

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

Currently I am making one folder with help of File class

```
String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home"); // this will  return C:\Users\username

byte[] b1 = abc.getValue(); // contains byte value

String dependentFile = "logoImageData"; // this is the folder name 

File f = new File(homeDir+"/"+ dependentFile); // after this line folder will be created like C:\Users\username\logoImageData

FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(homeDir+"/"+  abc.getName()); // assume abc.getName is image.jpg

fout.write(b1);  // this is writing the byte array data into location C:\Users\username\image.jpg
fout.close();
```

But I want the location to be C:\Users\username\logoImageData\image.jpg

Can please anyone point out what needs to be done to change the FileOutputStream location.
I tried and searched but unable to find out the exact thing.

I tried my best to detailed my problem. If still not clear then let me know I will try in another way.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

1) You're assuming that calling the `File` constructor will create a directory if it doesn't exist. That's not the case.

2) You're calling the `FileOutputStream` constructor and passing in the *home* directory, not the directory you want to create the file in.

I'd also advise you to use the `File(string, string)` and `File(File, String)` constructors to avoid all that string concatenation and hard-coding of directory separators... and use the "try with resources" statement to close the stream at the end... or even better, use `Files.write` to do it in one shot. Here's the `FileOutputStream` version:

```
String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");

File imageDirectory = new File(homeDir, "logoImageData");
// Create the directory if it doesn't exist.
imageDirectory.mkdir();
// TODO: Check the directory now exists, and *is* a directory...

File imageFile = new File(imageDirectory, abc.getName());
try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(imageFile)) {
    output.write(abc.getValue());
}
```

Comment: --thanks a lot Jon for such a quick response this is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`f` should contain the folder in which you wish to store the file :

```
FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(new File(f,abc.getName()));
```

Of course, you should make sure that folder exists and create it if necessary :

```
if (!f.exists ()) {
// -- create remote directory
    f.mkdirs ();
}
```